# MySQL Case Statement, Mutliple Rows Returned in 'Statement List' (the part after Then...)

Tags: mysql, subquery, case

Simply stated: I'm looking to put a subquery after the 'THEN' part of a CASE statement and it will be returning more than one row. Is this possible? More details below:

I'm looking for a way to get multiple rows back from a CASE statement even though the other fields in my SELECT statement only return one row. I keep getting 'Subquery returns more than one row.' That is what I want it to do!

TABLES:

```
courses
-------
course_id, fksubject_id;

course_reports
--------------
course_reports_id, fkcourse_id, is_finished, timestamp;

course_reports_answers
----------------------
course_reports_answers_id, fkcourse_reports_id, fkquestion_id, answer1, answer2, answer3
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT
   cr.course_reports_id,
   CASE WHEN c.fksubject_id = 1 THEN (SELECT fkquestion_id from course_reports_answers WHERE fkcourse_reports_id = 1) ELSE NULL END AS 'fkquestion_id'
FROM
courses c
join course_reports cr on cr.fkcourse_id = c.course_id
join course_reports_answers cra on cra.fkcourse_reports_id = cr.course_reports_id
```

So, because there are multiple fkquestion_ids per course_report_id, the desired result is:

```
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
etc.
```

Again, I'm getting 'Subquery returns more than one row.'

I'm trying to repeat a single value and pair it with different values, creating multiple rows. I think I've done this before, but I'm having a hard time finding my past query or figuring out whats wrong with what I'm doing now. NOTE: this SELECT will ultimately be used to populate an insert statement. ANY help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So if the course subject id isn't a 1, do you want it returned at all?

Comment: Actually, the real query will have a similar case for each possible subject_id and there will be some more parameters in the where clause limiting the results. I recognize (now) that how its written in the example would likely provide a bunch of NULL rows, but that won't be the case in the real query (which I can't provide because its for my employer.)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT
   cr.course_reports_id,
   Z.fkquestion_id
FROM
courses c
join course_reports cr on cr.fkcourse_id = c.course_id
join course_reports_answers cra on cra.fkcourse_reports_id = cr.course_reports_id
left outer join (SELECT cc.course_id, a.fkquestion_id from course_reports_answers a, courses cc WHERE cc.fksubject_id = 1 and a.fkcourse_reports_id = 1) Z on c.course_id = Z.course_id
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this version now, but I have to translate it back to my actual names. The part with fkcourse_reports_id = 1 in the subquery was by design. Basically, I want to copy all the answers from one model set of answers (the ones on fkcourse_reports_id = 1) and put them with different course_report_ids.

Comment: Awesome! I think this might work for me. Now I have to make a left outter join for each subject_id and also use a case statement in the SELECT to grab the right ones, I think it is working though.

Comment: glad that it works :-) Please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help.